# How this recursive call gets executed?

Tags: java, recursion

The following is a snippet to find the size of tree.How leftCount and rightCount values gets calculated at each recursive call.I understand recursion basically(which is each call gets into stack and returned when that called function is complete) but i cant visualize in this snippet.Can someone tell me how ?

```
public static int size(Node node){
   int leftCount = node.left == null ? 0 : size(node.left);
   int rightCount = node.right == null ? 0 : size(node.right);
   return 1+leftCount+rightCount;
 }
```

Edit : I understand recursions say `return n * fact(n-1)` .But in the above snippet there are two variables and their return statement makes use of both those variables so its kinda tough for me to understand.If this is too broad to explain can anyone post a simpler example with similar situation (using two variables).

Comment: Put breakpoint, put the log output into code and use debugger for better understanding. Your question is good, but too broad to explanation.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PT0mS3thy6Q) video. You will need a pen and paper to trace recursion, unless you are a debug king!

Comment: @Skynet The video is good, but can also be considered misleading for actual understanding because he's implicitly using memoization.  A clever human would do that, but the computer won't without explicit instructions.

Comment: @pjs I agree, I just meant to provide a basic example of how recursion can be traced, regardless of the problem kind.

Comment: Are you telling us that you don't know that `return 1 + leftCount + rightCount` will sum those three values and hand the result back to the point where *this level of the recursion* was called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to explain but I will attempt to do this. Using the debugger might give some more insight though.

For this explanation, we're assuming a tree with a size of 3. A root, left node and right node.
You call the method `size()` on the root of the tree. Now it will check if there is a left node, this is the case so the method is called upon the left node. `leftCount` within the left node will be 0 in this case because this node doesn't have a left node. The same will happen for `rightCount` since the left node of the root doesn't have a right node in our case. Now we're back in the method called on the root node. `leftCount` is 1 in this case because we returned 1+0+0. For the right node, the same thing will happen. It will return 1+0+0, this means `rightCount` will be 1. At the last line, we return 1+1+1 (which is correct). These are the sizes that were calculated.

This was a basic example, but I think you can better understand how this method works if you understand a simple case first.

EDIT: A video explaining this concept can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NA8B84DZYSA). The person in the video has an accent but this person explains similar code to yours.

Comment: I understand the basic example u said but what i dont understand is   `leftcount = return 1+leftcount+rightcount` and also for rightcount `rightcount = return 1+leftcount+rightcount` (Above code is syntactically wrong but i m just referring denotion ) .

Comment: Okay so `int leftCount = node.left == null ? 0 : size(node.left);` means that `leftCount` will be 0 if the current node does not have a left node (if the left node == null, there are no nodes to its left). Else, if there IS a node to the left, it will call the method with that node as parameter. It will continue to do so, until there is no left node. Then the right node of the 'lowest' left node will be checked in the same way (first the whole left side of it, then the right side). At every dead end, the current size will be returned. It's hard to explain in text, I will add a link above!

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting you might be getting stuck on this syntax, since it's not commonly taught, and I know several senior Java guys on my team who have to stop and mentally step thru it whenever they see one like this:

`int leftCount = node.left == null ? 0 : size(node.left);`

This is equivalent to:

```
int leftCount;
if (node.left == null) { 
  leftCount = 0; 
}
else 
  leftCount = size(node.left)
```

Comment: Nope ,  I understand this one .where i struck was at the below line                                 return 1+leftCount+rightCount;

Comment: @KarthikRaja In the base case, (where the node is a 'leaf', that is, both it's left and right are null), the method will return 1 + 0 + 0. In the recursive cases, it will return 1 + (size(node.left) + (size(node.right). Does that help or do I need to illustrate more?